# Mercurial 1.5.4 Can't Find osutil Module Using Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, python, mercurial

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and I just installed Mercurial 1.5.4 from source (see this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/157005/installing-mercurial-1-5-4-on-ubuntu-10-04) for some installation trouble that I had).  Now, however, when I invoke:

```
hg
```

I get the following:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/hg", line 27, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 47, in _load
    mod = _origimport(head, globals, locals)
ImportError: No module named osutil
```

yet

```
find /usr/local/lib -name osutil* -print
```

returns

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mercurial/osutil.so
```

which I assume can be loaded by Python scripts similar to Perl and XS.  With the exception of adding `python-dev` (see answer at above link) my Python installation is exactly as it came <strike>with Ubuntu 10.04</strike> after upgrading to 10.04 from 9.10.

What's going on?

Comment: from your earlier question, it seems the C modules are still not properly compiled. They should be with your manual install in `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/`.

Comment: Ok, so what do I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

This usually means you need to uninstall the `mercurial-common` package from Ubuntu - it can be earlier in the Python search path and cause weird problems like this.

Comment: This did it for me. I had a manual compiled Mercurial and remove the Ubuntu version first but had that package still around.

Answer (score 1):

Per http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Mercurial-1-5-2-released-td806821.html, you need the python-dev package.  For example, on Debian or Ubuntu, you would install it with

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

If that doesn't work right away, then re-do the Mercurial source installation, and that may solve the problem (it did for me).

Answer (score 0):

if you are running under windows you will find a folder "pure" inside of "\site-packages\mercurial\".
Inside of it, there are a bunch of .py (osutil.py is one of them)

Just copy all files inside "pure" to the "mercurial" folder and DONE! It just starts working.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This gave me 'ImportError: .py version of mercurial.osutil found where C version should exist.'

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of helping others, I just solved the missing `osutil.py` in Ubuntu 13.04, without which mercurial won't run.

I had to install python-sphinx (and related). This looks like a dependency check failure in the mercurial package.